# Special Relativity: Time dilation for two events happening in different positions both in $S$ and in $S'$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, time-dilation

In the derivation of the time dilation formula in Special Relativity, I have been taught that the position at which times are measured must be the same in one of the two reference systems: $S$ (which is taken to have zero velocity) or $S'$ (moving with velocity $v_x$ with respect to $S$):

$$\begin{array}
\centering
\begin{array}{l|ll}
&S&S' \rightarrow v_x\\ 
\hline
E_1&(x_1,t_1)&(x'_1,t'_1)\\  
E_2&(x_2,t_2)&(x'_2,t'_2)\\
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

1. If $E_1$ and $E_2$ happens at the same position in $S$: $x_1=x_2$

$$t_{1}^{\prime}=\gamma\left(t_{1}-\frac{\beta}{c} x_{1}\right), \space
t_{2}^{\prime}=\gamma\left(t_{2}-\frac{\beta}{c} x_{1}\right) \rightarrow 
\Delta t^{\prime}=\gamma \Delta t \tag{1}$$

2. If $E_1$ and $E_2$ happens at the same position in $S'$: $x'_1=x'_2$

$$t_{1}=\gamma\left(t'_{1}+\frac{\beta}{c} x'_{1}\right), \space
t_{2}=\gamma\left(t'_{2}+\frac{\beta}{c} x'_{1}\right) \rightarrow 
\Delta t=\gamma \Delta t' \tag{2}$$

But, what if events $E_1$ and $E_2$ happen in different positions both in $S$ and in $S'$? Does the expression of time dilation still apply if the position of the events is different?

---

For example, if a spaceship is moving with velocity $v$ with respect the Earth, and a light signal is sent from the Earth to the spaceship when it is at a distance $d$ from the Earth, it can be easily found that $t_2=\frac{d}{c-v}$

$$\begin{array}
\centering
\begin{array}{l|ll}
&S&S' \rightarrow v_x\\ 
\hline
E_1: \text{light signal is sent}&(0,0)&(-d,0)\\  
E_2: \text{light signal is received}&(x_2,t_2)&(0,t'_2)\\
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

Would it be possible to apply time dilation formula $(1)$ or $(2)$ to find $t'_2$ from $t_2$? Cause, using Lorentz contraction, you get the same result that by using time dilation (which I thought could not be applied in this case):

$t_{2}=\frac{d}{c-v} \rightarrow $ $x_{2}=c t_{2}=\frac{d c}{c-v} \rightarrow$ $x_{2}^{\prime}=\frac{x_{2}}{\gamma}=\frac{d c}{\gamma(c-v)} \rightarrow$ $t^{\prime}_{2}=\frac{x_{2}^{\prime}}{c}=\frac{d}{\gamma(c-v)}=\frac{t_2}{\gamma}\rightarrow$ $\Delta t'_2=\Delta t_2 / \gamma$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103943/discussion-on-question-by-quaerendo-special-relativity-time-dilatation-for-two).

Answer (score 2):

As an example consider this, suppose you are in a traveling carriage and you flash a light 2 seconds apart. Now, in your frame the event is happening at the same place at two different times but for someone standing on a carriage by your side (at a slower velocity) it is happening at two different positions and two different times, and for someone standing on a platform it is happening at other two different positions at two different times.

The time dilation you have stated above has these two reference frames:

1) The frame of the event
2) The frame of the observer

For someone on the platform time is more "dilated" than the carriage beside you and for the carriage beside you it is more dilated than your carriage frame and less dilated than the platform frame.

For the example of Earth, the time dilation equation should be,

$t_1=[t'_1+\frac{v}{c²}(-d)]γ$

$t_2=[t'_2+\frac{v}{c²}(0)]γ$

$t_2-t_1 = [Δt' + (d\frac{v}{c²})] γ $

I hope it clears some of the doubt if not all